# How do i find GCD with while loop? How does modulus operator work?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while

```
#include <iostream>

int GCD()
{
    int a,b,k;
    cout<<"Enter a and b"<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<endl;

    if (a>b)
    {
        k=a;
    }
    else
    {
        k=b;
    }

    cout<<k<<endl;

    do
    {
        k=k-1;
    } while(a%k !=0 && b%k !=0);

    cout<<k<<endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Why programm like this doesnt work correctly? For example when i enter 125 and 5 answer is 25, but supposed to be 5? Am wrong with logic in while loop? As i understood problem is in modulus operator. When `k` hits `25` it says that `125%25=0` and `5%=25=0`. How can i fix this?

Comment: Try to test with multiple test cases and debug your code. Hint: condition under `while` is WRONG!! You should check for equality and not inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes here:

1. The GCD is lower or equal to the *lower* number. Currently, you start checking with the larger number. You need to flip the `if` block to `if (a<b)`. (not exactly an error, but you check much more numbers than needed)
2. You need to check if the inital k is the GCD. When using a `do {} while()` the first number you check is `k-1`. Use a simple `while` instead. Also the loop condition has a logic flaw.

```
while (!((a % k == 0) && (b % k == 0)))
{
    k--;
}
```

Note that the brackets around the modulo are not neccessary, but improve readability a bit.

3. Your code will not compile under all compilers and you should not omit the namespace `std::`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` statement has logic error. It needs to be

```
while(!(a%k == 0 && b%k == 0));
```

When `k` is equal to 25, `125%25==0` so in your `while` statement `a%k !=0` part is equals to false so it exit your `do-while` but it needs to test if `b%k` is equal to 0 or not!

Also your implementation tends to execute slow when `a` and `b` is big. You can take a look efficent [solutions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-find-gcd-hcf-two-numbers/).